# Matlab For Loop Image

Tags: image, matlab, for-loop, image-processing

I am trying to open a `.pgm` image file in MATLAB, run a manipulation with a for loop and then save as another .pgm file. Before doing the manipulation I was testing to see if I could recreate the image:

```
clear

picture = imread('Picture.pgm');

sizePic = size(picture);

sizeX = sizePic(1);
sizeY = sizePic(2);

newPicture = zeros(sizeX,sizeY);


for i = 1:sizeX
    for j = 1:sizeY
        newPicture(i,j) = picture(i,j);
    end
end

imwrite(newPicture, 'NewPicture.pgm');
```

However, the new image is almost all white with some black splotches (not the original). Shouldn't this just give me back the original image?

Comment: Most likely has to do with the default encoding options in `imread` and `imwrite`. I would suggest checking documentation for the functions and then the encoding in your image file.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `picture` created from imread(XXX.pgm) is either a `uint8` or `uint16` array, meaning the pixel values are in the range of [0 255] or [0 65535]. On the other hand, `newPicture` created from `zeros` is a `double` array, the expected pixel value for which is only [0 1]. Any value greater than 1 will be interpreted as 1 (white) in the saved image. When you assign a [0 255] value to such a `double` array, since most of the pixel values in `picture` is 1 and above, of course you will get mostly white pixels

When you work with images, always check the type of the image array. For example, it may be a good idea to always work with `double` type by explicitly converting the image returned by imread as such:
`pictures=im2double(imread(xxx))`.